# Alternative for management.getSelf in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-web-extension

guys
I'm developing an extension for Safari using web browser api but Safari does not support management object and getSelft() function
Does anyone know how to check if the extension is installed in development mode?

```
window.browser.management.getSelf(({ installType }) => {
        if(installType === "development") {
            // Do some stuff...
        }
})
```